# Should I check cancellation_date_ms in addition to expires_date_ms for a auto-renewable subscriptions?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewable

I am implementing an auto-renewable subscription in my app.

Currently, to check if the user have an active subscription, I examine all the records in `latest_receipt_info` array from the response JSON returned from the Apple's `/verifyReceipt` service, find the one with the max `expires_date_ms` and check if this date is in the future. Before checking the dates I also check if the `status` field is 0 (receipt is valid).

I was thinking that it is enough, but I recently found out that there is another field - `cancellation_date_ms`. As I understand from the docs, this filed is present if user has canceled his subscription through the Apple support.

From ([Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/cancellation_date_ms))

> You can use this value to:
>
> Determine whether to stop providing the content associated with the
>   purchase.
>
> Check for any latest renewal transactions, which may indicate the user
>   re-started or upgraded their subscription, for an auto-renewable
>   subscription purchase.

So I am wondering, if a user cancels his subscription through the Apple support, will this affect the `expires_date_ms` for the current subscription period? So the next time I check `expires_date_ms`, I know the subscription is not active.

Or does `expires_date_ms` stays the same as it was before the user canceled the subscription, and so I need to check the `cancellation_date_ms` as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check for `cancellation_date_ms` as well. `Expires_date` field doesn't change when customer cancels subscription through Apple Support.

Here is production JSON example with refund:

```
"latest_receipt_info": [
    {
        "quantity": "1",
        "product_id": "XXX",
        "transaction_id": "150000567873035",
        "original_transaction_id": "150000567873035",
        "purchase_date": "2019-11-10 17:37:05 Etc/GMT",
        "purchase_date_ms": "1573407425000",
        "purchase_date_pst": "2019-11-10 09:37:05 America/Los_Angeles",
        "original_purchase_date": "2019-11-10 17:37:06 Etc/GMT",
        "original_purchase_date_ms": "1573407426000",
        "original_purchase_date_pst": "2019-11-10 09:37:06 America/Los_Angeles",
        "expires_date": "2019-12-10 17:37:05 Etc/GMT",
        "expires_date_ms": "1575999425000",
        "expires_date_pst": "2019-12-10 09:37:05 America/Los_Angeles",
        "cancellation_date": "2019-12-05 19:14:48 Etc/GMT",
        "cancellation_date_ms": "1575573288000",
        "cancellation_date_pst": "2019-12-05 11:14:48 America/Los_Angeles",
        "web_order_line_item_id": "150000194283402",
        "is_trial_period": "false",
        "is_in_intro_offer_period": "false",
        "cancellation_reason": "0",
        "subscription_group_identifier": "20502261"
    }
],
"pending_renewal_info": [
    {
        "auto_renew_product_id": "XXX",
        "original_transaction_id": "150000567873035",
        "product_id": "XXX",
        "auto_renew_status": "0"
    }
]}
```

Comment: If a user cancel auto renewable subscription for not renewing and no money refund, will there a cancellation_date_ms ? Or cancellation_date_ms is unique for just refund ?

Comment: This field is available only in production, and does not appear in sandbox receipts [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/cancellation_date_ms).